# Google Play Invoicing: Which entity should be the recipient of an Invoice for selling IAPs?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, invoice, tax

I'm from EU (not Ireland) and need to invoice one of the Google entities for all IAP transactions that were in my app in the last month but I just can't, for the love of me, find any info on any of my accounts as to whom should I invoice. I realize that I don't need to actually send the invoice anywhere if I'm from outside of Ireland but I still need to create the invoice for the sake of taxes in my country.

I found two Google entities that might be suitable but am still not sure which one will it be (as I didn't actually receive the payment yet):

- GOOGLE IRELAND LIMITED vat number: IE 6388047 V
- GOOGLE COMMERCE LIMITED vat number: IE 9825613 N

Does any one have any experience with that and could point me in the right direction?

**Another question is about the Google commission**. As far as I know, I can count this commission as income cost but I'm still not sure on how to do that properly yet. Will I get an Invoice for this amount from Google after the actual payment is done? Or do I have to calculate this value from the monthly reports available in Google Play Console?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As I came across the same question two years later, this is what I found out in case it might be relevant for someone else:

> GOOGLE IRELAND LIMITED vat number: IE 6388047 V

This is the company Google uses for AdSense payments and handling. Information about that can be found in the [Google AdSense Help](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1322031).

> GOOGLE COMMERCE LIMITED vat number: IE 9825613 N

This is the company Google uses for Google Store/Google Pay/Google Play Store handling. Sadly I have not found any clue on that information in the Play Console Help, however you can go to [payments.google.com](https://payments.google.com), open the Activities tab, select any payment and download the invoice where you will find the VAT-ID as well as the belonging address.

Regarding the second question as Google pays you, you have to write an invoice which you actually do not need to send to Google as they do not care, but which is for your accounting only. I would just use the amount you have been paid to your bank account. But this is no tax advice and you should get in touch with a tax consultant (just a disclaimer here).

Answer (score 0):

For me (Italy) the right entity is:

- Google Payment Ireland Ltd
- 70 Sir John Rogerson's Quay, Dublin 2
- Ireland
- VAT: IE3463004VH